# get percentage from count from a unique column values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

Hi I have a table as below

```
 k_id |l_id |count | avg
----------------------------------
|  1  | 10  |  4   |  
|  1  | 10  |  3   | 
|  1  | 10  |  2   | 
|  1  | 10  |  1   | 
|  1  | 10  |  1   |
|  1  |  9  |  1   |
|  3  |  8  |  1   |
|  2  |  7  |  1   |
```

in a select statement, I am trying to get the percentage from the count, but I don't want to include all the rows. I want to count individually where k_id and l_id are unique.

right now I have a select sub_query like below:

```
SELECT k_id, l_id, count, 100.0 * count / sum(count) over () AS avg
FROM (                
      select k_id, l_id, count(m_id) as count
         from schema.table                                
               group by k_id, l_id order by count desc
           ) a
     group by k_id, l_id, count
```

actual results:

```
 k_id |l_id |count | avg
-------------------------
|  1  | 10  |  4   | 28.57 
|  1  | 10  |  3   | 21.42
|  1  | 10  |  2   | 14.28
|  1  | 10  |  1   | 7.14
|  1  | 10  |  1   | 7.14
|  1  |  9  |  1   | 7.14
|  3  |  8  |  1   | 7.14
|  2  |  7  |  1   | 7.14
```

how can I get the below results

Expected results:

```
k_id |l_id |count | avg
-------------------------
|  1  | 10  |  4   | 36.36 
|  1  | 10  |  3   | 27.27
|  1  | 10  |  2   | 18.18
|  1  | 10  |  1   | 9.09
|  1  | 10  |  1   | 9.09
|  1  |  9  |  1   | 100.00
|  3  |  8  |  1   | 100.00
|  2  |  7  |  1   | 100.00
```

Thanks.

Comment: in your subquery add a sum(m_id) field.

Comment: Hi @imran, I cant sum m_id, as that field is character varying. Thanks

Comment: Where is column `m_id` in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `PARTITION` your `SUM` over `k_id, l_id`. That way you get the average using `k_id, l_id = 1, 10` instead of the entire `sum(count)`.

```
SELECT
  k_id, l_id, count,
  100.0 * count / sum(count) OVER (PARTITION BY k_id, l_id) AS avg
FROM ( ... )
ORDER BY l_id DESC;

 k_id | l_id | count |         avg
------+------+-------+----------------------
    1 |   10 |     4 |  36.3636363636363636
    1 |   10 |     3 |  27.2727272727272727
    1 |   10 |     2 |  18.1818181818181818
    1 |   10 |     1 |   9.0909090909090909
    1 |   10 |     1 |   9.0909090909090909
    1 |    9 |     1 | 100.0000000000000000
    3 |    8 |     1 | 100.0000000000000000
    2 |    7 |     1 | 100.0000000000000000
```